# Can not read property 'pattern' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input

I hava write two input box and add the pattern attribute to them.but when I enter something in the first box, it work without any problem, but when I enter the second one , it throws a lot of eceptions! I don't know what is wrong with the code, here is my error.

```
    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js?09c9:11062)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10459)
    at callViewAction (core.js?09c9:10700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js?09c9:10663)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10460)
    at callViewAction (core.js?09c9:10700)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js?09c9:10663)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js?09c9:10460)
    at callViewAction (core.js?09c9:10700)

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 9, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

and here is my html code:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
     #password="ngModel"  pattern="^[A-z0-9_]+$"
    placeholder="{{'global.form.newpassword.placeholder' | translate}}"
    [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.password" minlength=5 maxlength=30 required>

<input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" #confirmPasswordInput="ngModel" pattern="^[A-z0-9_]+$"
placeholder="{{'global.form.confirmpassword.placeholder' | translate}}"
[(ngModel)]="confirmPassword" minlength=5 maxlength=30 required>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password"
placeholder="{{'global.form.newpassword.placeholder' | translate}}"
     #password="ngModel"  pattern="^[A-z0-9_]+$"
    [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.password" minlength=5 maxlength=30 required>`

`<input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" #confirmPasswordInput="ngModel" pattern="^[A-z0-9_]+$"
placeholder="{{'global.form.confirmpassword.placeholder' | translate}}"
[(ngModel)]="confirmPasswordTest" minlength=5 maxlength=30 required>`

Comment: thank you, I  fond the bug just 30min ago, I  forgot to change the parameter's name when I copy a  piece of code.